# zsh custom theme, command completion bug

Tags: shell, autocomplete, zsh, customization

i'm making my own custom zsh theme, everything is working fine except the command autocompletion.
when I press Tab to autocomplete my command, it let what i've wrote and autocomplete after duplicating inital input

$cat .oh-my-zsh/custom/theme/leslie.zsh-theme

```
function get_pwd() {
  echo "${PWD/$HOME/~}"
}

function get_branch(){
  if git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree > /dev/null 2>&1; then 
   echo -n "[$(git branch --show-current)]"
  else
  fi
}

function put_spacing() {
  local termwidth  
  (( termwidth =  ${COLUMNS} - ${#$(get_pwd)} -11 - ${#user}  -  ${#$(get_branch)} ))
  local spacing=""
  for i in {1..$termwidth}; do
    spacing="${spacing} "
  done
  echo $spacing
}

local user=%n

PROMPT="%B%(?:$FG[128] :$FG[160] )"
PROMPT+='$fg[cyan][$user]%b:  $fg[cyan]$(get_pwd)$reset_color$(put_spacing)%B$FG[128]$(get_branch)%b'
PROMPT+="%(?:$FG[128]:$FG[160])⮑  %{$reset_color%}"
```

$cat .zshrc

```
export ZSH="/Users/leslie/.oh-my-zsh"
ZSH_THEME="leslie"
plugins=(git)
source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
```

my bug:

```
 [leslie]:  ~                                                              
⮑  cd D           cd Desktop/
```

[My Bug in picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ca7da.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
function get_pwd() {
  echo "${PWD/$HOME/~}"
}

function get_branch(){
  if git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree > /dev/null 2>&1; then 
   echo -n "[$(git branch --show-current)]"
  else
  fi
}

function put_spacing() {
  local termwidth  
  (( termwidth =  ${COLUMNS} - ${#$(get_pwd)} -11 - ${#user}  -  ${#$(get_branch)} ))
  local spacing=""
  for i in {1..$termwidth}; do
    spacing="${spacing} "
  done
  echo $spacing
}

local user=%n

PROMPT="%B%(?:$FG[128] :$FG[160] )"
PROMPT+='$fg[cyan][$user]%b:  $fg[cyan]$(get_pwd)%{$reset_color%}$(put_spacing)%B$FG[128]$(get_branch)%b
%(?:$FG[128]:$FG[160])⮑  %{$reset_color%}'
```

removing the last PROMT+= solved my problem, if someone have an explaination i'll be glad to hear it. :)